# Some binary tree based operations

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am trying to print the non-leaf(Internal) nodes in a binary search tree . But I am not getting the desired output . Kindly rectify my error or suggest me some better algorithm .
Here is my code .

```
void noleaf(struct node *here)
{
      if((temp -> left != NULL) || (temp -> right != NULL))
      {
         printf("%d" , temp -> data) ;
         if(temp -> left != NULL)
         {
            noleaf(temp -> left) ;
         }
      }
      noleaf(temp -> right) ;
      return 0 ;
}
```

Another function asks me to print the mirror image of the tree . Here I used .

```
struct node *Mirror(struct node *t)
{
    if(t == NULL)
    {
        return 0 ;
    }
    else
    {
        nn = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ;
        nn -> data = t -> data ;
        nn -> left = Mirror(t -> right);
        nn -> right = Mirror(t -> left) ;
        return nn ;
    }
}
```

I am new to binary trees . Kindly help .

Comment: shouldn't there be an `else` matching the `if(temp->left)` before `noleaf(temp->right)` in `noleaf()`? As in, it can currently be called when `temp->right == NULL`.

Comment: Why are you using `temp` and not `here`?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic looks like this:

- If the node has at least one child, print its data, and then

  - if the node has a left child, recurse into that
- Then, recurse into the right child, regardless of whether it exists.

I think you'll agree that printing only nodes that have at least one child, and treating one child differently than the other, is unfair.

Recursion on binary trees usually take one of the following forms:

- If it is a leaf, do your leaf processing (common for all cases)
- Otherwise, either

  - do your internal node processing and then recurse into the subtrees (preorder), or
  - recurse into the subtrees and then do your internal node processing (postorder), or
  - recurse into the left subtree, then do your internal node processing, then recurse into the right subtree (inorder).

So a preorder traversal version of `noleaf` might be

```
void noleaf(struct node *here)
{
    if (here == NULL)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d", here->data);
        noleaf(here->left);
        noleaf(here->right);
    }
}
```

or, simplified

```
void noleaf(struct node *here)
{
    if (here)
    {
        printf("%d", here->data);
        noleaf(here->left);
        noleaf(here->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to distinguish non-leaf nodes when printing the tree? I have re-sequenced your instructions (and omitted a return value - your compiler should have warned you about that).

```
void printree(struct node *here)
{
    if (here != NULL)
    {
        printree (here->left);
        printf("%d\n", here -> data) ;
        printree (here->right);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the noleaf function you have to check if here is not NULL (if it's NULL here->left or here->right will cause a segmentation fault or an error), then you have to check if here have sons, if it does have at least one then we aren't in a leaf, if we are then we print the content of the node.

```
void noleaf(struct node * here) {
    if (here)
        if (here->left || tree->right) {
            printf("%d\n",here->data);
            noleaf(here->left);
            noleaf(here->right);
        }
}
```

**Note**: One thing that I didn't understand was why you were using temp and not here.